# PHPUnit test failed

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phpunit

I'm currently trying to run PHPUnit on my Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine and when I run `phpunit` under my application root that has `phpunit.xml.dist` file it reads from the config but I'm getting below error and it fails:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Test::getHookMethods() in phar:///usr/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 633
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: what is your phpunit version?

Comment: how did you installed phpunit?

Comment: @ferozakbar PHPUnit version is 4.0.12

Comment: @hek2mgl using `sudo pear install -a -f --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit`

Comment: Did you use a bootstrap and include PHPUnit in the include_path?

Comment: I used `pear` to install and `phpunit` command seems to be working fine in console it just happens when I run in the root of the project file with `phpunit.xml.dist` file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in a different environment.
The problem was that another library's loader was registered too early which also contained another version of PHPUnit which had no that method. The proper order of autoloaders solved the problem.